# ReportLab Plus in Azure Websites?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, reportlab

I have ASP.NET MVC hosted in Azure(Website). I wanna integrate ReportLab in my application. According to [FAQ](http://www.reportlab.com/software/documentation/faq/), Python should be installed in order use ReportLab. But I don't think Azure website will allow me install anything. Two questions,

1) Can we integrate ReportLab in ASP.NET MVC and host it as Azure Website?
2) How can we pass model object to RML(XML)? The [example](http://www.reportlab.com/software/documentation/sample-projects/rml-with-dotnet/) is just executing an exe.

Answer (score 0):

Azure does allow you to use Python.  "You can select the version of Python that you want to use in the Azure Websites portal by opening the Configure tab of your website and changing the Python Version setting."

source: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-python-configure/

Comment: No. I have already ASP.NET Website on Azure. How can enable Python there.